# How to get notified the user shared something using ShareKit?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sharekit

I'm using ShareKit to allow users to share stuff from my app to Twitter and Facebook. After the user shared the object, I would like to get my app notified about it, in order to pass an API call to my server - so it can handle notifying the users "your friend just shared something, look it up!".

Facebook SDK allows to get a callback with information like the post ID. I'm wondering how to achieve something like this when using ShareKit 2.0 - should I override some methods of the Facebook and Twitter sharers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that modifying the ShareKit was the simplest (?) option.

In the `SHKFacebook.m` file, in the

```
-(void)FBRequestHandlerCallback:(FBRequestConnection *)connection
                         result:(id) result
                          error:(NSError *)error
```

method the result parameter actually contains what I needed - it is a dictionary-like object that has the `id` key - and the value is a string containing the FB id of the post:

```
result: {
    id = "XXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";
}
```

So what I actually did was adding a `@property (nonatomic, strong) id sharingResult` to the base `SHKSharer` class and setting it to the `result` value just before calling the `[self didFinishSending]` in `FBRequestHandlerCallback`. This allows me to access the result in sharingDelegate later, in a `- (void) sharerFinishedSending:(SHKSharer *)sharer` method.

Answer (score 2):

All `SHKSharer`s provide a delegate mechanism that you can use to be notified of the success / failure of the share (or authorisation). Check the superclass docs / .h file.

Comment: But is there a way to get into the response from Facebook? As it should give me the link to the shared post.

Comment: I think you'd either have to modify share kit to do that, or, when you get the delegate callback then you can call FB to request the data.